# How can I return type T from Func delegate?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, func

I have a class that defines a generic Add method like this:

```
public T Add(T item){
```

within that method I want to dynamically call the correct method for the type, so for example if I had:

```
private Foo AddFoo(Foo f){
    //do foo adding stuff
}

private Bar AddBar(Bar b){
    //do bar adding stuff
}
```

//etc, many more types

How can I get my Add method to invoke the correct one for my type? It seems like I could use Func delegates here but I'm struggling to work it out. Much thanks!

Note: overloading Add for the different types is not an option because the class implements the Add method from an interface (and it's not my interface to change)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the question is.  Can you elaborate further, or provide a more complete example?  Why use generics here at all?  Overloading `Add` seems the correct course of action.

Comment: Why do you even *have* those different methods? Either all your classes have anything in common which makes them a good fit for generics, or they don´t, in which case you should not use generics at all.

Comment: Why not just use the type then? Override them with different methods, aka `public Foo Add(Foo item)` ... `public Bar Add(Bar item)`...

Comment: Then your interface is broken. A generic assumes there **is** something common between your types, which does not seem to be the case here.

Comment: @HimBromBeere - its not my interface

Comment: If only two classes can qualify then it is not generic.  And trying to make it generic is a mistake, use overloads.

Comment: Well then someone else's interface is broken :)

Comment: Consider explicit interface implementation with public overloads of `Add` methods which will call private generic version

Answer (score 2):

Why not overload the `Add` method?

```
public Foo Add(Foo f) { ... }
public Bar Add(Bar f) { ... }
public Baz Add(Baz f) { ... }
public Pony Add(Pony f) { ... }
```

The correct overload will automatically be chosen by the compiler.  If an object is passed into `Add` that isn't a `Foo`, `Bar`, `Baz`, or `Pony`, the compiler will emit an error.  This would not be true if you use generics and write your own dispatch.

If you use generics:

```
public T Add<T>(T obj) { ... }
```

Then the compiler will allow you to write:

```
Add(new Widget());
```

which would result in a *runtime* exception.  This solution is not advisable.  You gain nothing and lose the benefits of the type system.

Regarding your edit:

> overloading Add for the different types is not an option because the class implements the Add method from an interface

**I recommend you fix this interface.**  This interface is broken and should be fixed.  Generics should not be used to create a catch-all method that only performs dispatch while tossing the static type system out. Your usage of generics here is no different from simply using `object` as the return and parameter types.

If fixing this interface is not an option, go with the other answer.

Answer (score -1):

With C# 7.1 or newer you can implement it with pattern matching as:

```
public T Add<T>(T item)
{
    switch (item)
    {
        case Foo a: return (T)(object) AddFoo(a);
        case Bar b: return (T)(object) AddBar(b);
        default: throw new InvalidOperationException(typeof(T) + " is not supported!");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's Haskell Style!

Comment: Just because you can does not mean you should. This defeats the object of using a generic so why bother? The same thing can be achieved by just [using an override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56277745/how-can-i-return-type-t-from-func-delegate#comment99170012_56277745)

Comment: Given the OP's constraints (e.g. *it's not my interface to change*), this is actually a correct answer.